# Python package R&D in Dask Distributed

Tags: python, development-environment, distributed, dask

Posting this here as I was asked to in the Dask Gitter Channel.

Sharing production packages in Dask is straight forward.  We simply add it a base Docker image or startup script for the scheduler and workers.  During R&D / Development this process is quite cumbersome when rapidly making changes to a Python Package.

I've used upload_file, in an interactive Jupyter notebook.  However, once the package is pushed subsequent upload_files do not appear to update the package.  Resetting the kernel appears to be the only way to do so.  What is the current workflow that others have used to update these packages across the cluster in an interactive fashion?

Answer:
The packages were actually updating but the module definition is not updated in the notebook.  Using [autoreload](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html) may be a possible solution.

Comment: I believe that workers already reload modules if they are uploaded again.  How have you determined that this doesn't already work as-is?  Also, please note that dask workers don't run in Jupyter kernels, so part of your question at least is somewhat confusing.  Are you asking about how to reload a module in your local kernel?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the following:
1) is to make sure the latest code is uploaded the the workers (which is probably happening)
2) update the function definitions in the Jupyter Notebook, which probably requires reloading the module in the notebook

I believe I was assuming that if the uploaded module was sent to the cluster the local dask client would also get the latest module which does not seem to be occurring.

Comment: I think I can accomplish what I need by using [autoreload](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html) in the notebook so the definitions match up

Comment: When you say "the local dask client would also get the latest module" this isn't actually how things work.  Dask doesn't own your local process and can't manage it.  Instead you manage it with tools like python, ipython, or jupyter.  This is something that you'll have to solve on your own with help from those tools.

Answer (score 0):

The `Client.upload_file` command already reloads modules if they are sent again.

You'll have to manage your own local process normally.  Dask has no control over this.  You might consider the `importlib.reload` function, but I suspect that there are several questions on Stack Overflow on this topic that are not Dask related that would be helpful here.